# Is there a precedent for Israel calling for the resignation of the organization’s secretary-general?

Tags: israel, united-nations

> Speaking on Tuesday at a meeting of the U.N. Security Council,
> Guterres reiterated his call for a humanitarian pause of Israel’s
> offensive in the Gaza Strip, which has been sealed off from Israel’s
> supplies of fuel, food, water and electricity. Israel is carrying out
> a military campaign against Palestinian militant group Hamas, which
> launched a multipronged attack against Israel two weeks prior.
>
> While stating he has “condemned unequivocally the horrifying and
> unprecedented 7 October acts of terror by Hamas in Israel,” Guterres
> said “it is important to also recognize the attacks by Hamas did not
> happen in a vacuum,” pointing to “56 years of suffocating occupation”
> suffered by the Palestinian people.

https://www.cnbc.com/2023/10/25/antonio-guterres-israel-envoy-calls-for-un-chiefs-resignation.html

Is there a precedent for Israel calling for the resignation of the organization’s secretary-general? The UN secretary general made a controversial comment about the situation in Gaza, and as a result Israel called for his resignation. Did this ever happen before, is there a precedent for this, or is this the first time Israel called for the resignation of the secretary general at the UN?

Comment: Not sure about Israel, but such calls generally are not that uncommon https://www.upi.com/Archives/1994/04/23/Mahathir-calls-for-UN-chiefs-job/6577767073600/